# XML Parsing to c# objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, xml-parsing

I am trying to do a XML parser which will extract data from a website using REST service, the protocol for communication is HTTP, the data I get is in XML format, and I get to the data I need after several requests to different addresses on the server. I need to parse this data to c# objects so I can operate with them lately.
The information on the server is on 5 levels( I am willing to make work only 4 of them for know)
1-List of vendors
2-List of groups
3-List of subgroups
4-List of products
5-List of full information about products
After I get to 4th level I need to check if the product is in my database or if it has different details so I can add or update it.

With "GET" request to a server I get XML with this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
     <vendors>
              <vendor>
                      <id>someID</id>
                      <name>someName</name>
              </vendor>
              <vendor>
                      <id>someId1</id>
                      <name>somename1</name>
              </vendor>
     </vendors>
```

XML structure for groups is the same :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<groups vendor_id="43153185318">
         <group>
               <id>someID</id>
               <name>someName</name>
         </group>
         <group>
               <id>someId1</id>
               <name>somename1</name>
         </group>
```

The XML structure is analogical for subgroups and products, except that for products I have more elements like catalog_num, price etc.

I made the classes as follows :

```
public class VendorList
    {
            public List<Vendor> vendor_list { get; set; }
            public VendorList()
            {
                    vendor_list = new List<Vendor>();
            }
    }
    public class Vendor
    {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public List<Group> groups_list { get; set; }
            public Vendor()
            {
                    id = "N/A";
                    name = "N/A";
                    groups_list = new List<Group>();
            }
    }
    public class Group
    {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public List<SubGroup> subgroup_list { get; set; }
            public Group()
            {
                    id = "N/A";
                    name = "N/A";
                    subgroup_list = new List<SubGroup>();
            }
    }
    public class SubGroup
    {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public List<Product> product_list { get; set; }
            public SubGroup()
            {
                    id = "N/A";
                    name = "N/A";
                    product_list = new List<Product>();
            }
    }
    public class Product
    {
            public string available { get; set; }
            public string catalog_num { get; set; }
            public string code { get; set; }
            public string currency { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string haracteristics { get; set; }
            public string product_id { get; set; }
            public string model { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string price { get; set; }
            public string price_dds { get; set; }
            public string picture_url { get; set; }
            public Product()
            {
                    available = "N/A";
                    catalog_num = "N/A";
                    code = "N/A";
                    currency = "N/A";
                    description = "N/A";
                    haracteristics = "N/A";
                    product_id = "N/A";
                    model = "N/A";
                    name = "N/A";
                    price = "N/A";
                    price_dds = "N/A";
                    picture_url = "N/A";
            }
    }
```

and the Parser method like this :

```
            public static void FillVendor(string url)
            {
                    string result = GetXMLstream(url);
                    var vendors = new VendorList();
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(new StringReader(result));
                    doc.Save(@"D:/proba/proba.xml");
                    XDocument d = XDocument.Load(@"D:/proba/proba.xml");
                    vendors.vendor_list = (from c in d.Descendants("vendor")
                                                               select new Vendor()
                                                               {
                                                                       id = c.Element("id").Value,
                                                                       name = c.Element("name").Value
                                                               }).ToList<Vendor>();
                    foreach (Vendor v in vendors.vendor_list)
                    {
                            FillGroups(v.id);
                    }
            }
            public static void FillGroups(string vendorID)
            {
                    string url = "main address" + vendorID;
                    string result = GetXMLstream(url);
                    var group = new Vendor();
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(new StringReader(result));
                    doc.Save(@"D:/proba/proba1.xml");
                    XDocument d = XDocument.Load(@"D:/proba/proba1.xml");
                    group.groups_list = (from g in d.Descendants("group")
                                                             select new Group()
                                                             {
                                                                     id = g.Element("id").Value,
                                                                     name = g.Element("name").Value
                                                             }).ToList<Group>();
                    foreach (Group g in group.groups_list)
                    {
                            FillSubGroup(vendorID, g.id);
                    }
            }
            public static void FillSubGroup(string vendorID, string groupID)
            {
                    string url = "main address" + vendorID+"/"+groupID;
                    string result = GetXMLstream(url);
                    var subgroup = new Group();
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(new StringReader(result));
                    doc.Save(@"D:/proba/proba2.xml");
                    XDocument d = XDocument.Load(@"D:/proba/proba2.xml");
                    subgroup.subgroup_list = (from g in d.Descendants("subgroup")
                                                             select new SubGroup()
                                                             {
                                                                     id = g.Element("id").Value,
                                                                     name = g.Element("name").Value
                                                             }).ToList<SubGroup>();
                    foreach (SubGroup sb in subgroup.subgroup_list)
                    {
                            FillProduct(vendorID, groupID, sb.id);
                    }
            }
            public static void FillProduct(string vendorID,string groupID,string subgroupID)
            {
                    string url = "main address" + vendorID + "/" + groupID+"/"+subgroupID;
                    string result = GetXMLstream(url);
                    var product = new SubGroup();
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(new StringReader(result));
                    doc.Save(@"D:/proba/proba2.xml");
                    XDocument d = XDocument.Load(@"D:/proba/proba2.xml");
                    product.product_list = (from g in d.Descendants("subgroup")
                                                                      select new Product()
                                                                      {
                                                                              available = g.Element("available").Value,
                                                                              catalog_num = g.Element("catalog_num").Value,
                                                                              code = g.Element("code").Value,
                                                                              currency = g.Element("currency").Value,
                                                                              description = g.Element("description").Value,
                                                                              haracteristics = g.Element("haracteristics").Value,
                                                                              product_id = g.Element("id").Value,
                                                                              model = g.Element("model").Value,
                                                                              name = g.Element("name").Value,
                                                                              price = g.Element("price").Value,
                                                                              price_dds = g.Element("price_dds").Value,
                                                                              picture_url = g.Element("small_picture").Value,
                                                                      }).ToList<Product>();
            }
```

But after finishing parsing I try to check if my Lists are populated with objects, but I get an error which says that they are null "NullReferenceException"
So my question is did I make classes properly and is my parsing method right ( you can suggest how to parse the xml without creating a file on my computer) and if I didn't where is my mistake and how should I make it work properly?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
modify this line add 's'( vendor -> vendors)

-> vendors.vendor_list = (from c in d.Descendants("vendor")

and the same case for group -> groups
```

Comment: In my opinion the problem is in the class definion but can't see what is wrong :X

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the classes yourself.

Create a properly formatted XML Schema either manually or with Visual Studio and then from that XSD File you've created generate your C# Classes.

Comment: FYI, `xsd.exe` can actually grok XML-by-example without having to go through the hasssle of writing up a proper XSD.